# Retro-analysing an Internet Message

Tags: email

```
Received: from systemalerts9.mailchimp.com (Unknown [127.0.0.1])
    by 12c7dd814f66 (Haraka/2.8.26) with ESMTP id 041FFD0C-7FD1-4931-B50E-E2CE575EE393.1
    envelope-from <bounce-mcsys.usx_0.0f94103947-yapirar954=mayhco.com@systemalerts9.mailchimp.com>;
    Thu, 18 Feb 2021 20:21:29 +0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mailchimp.com; s=k2;
    t=1613679689; i=clientservices@mailchimp.com;
    bh=+iNaGHPEm8j211HI/b/X+81aoIUtWTtywFk3fff9mfs=;
    h=From:Reply-To:To:Date:Message-ID:Subject:MIME-Version:
     Content-Type;
    b=PjBCeQm1UoT9azGekl1rwOy72ohCGGB5B+YPNlUC2xU8u4aXhE9zSkXDrhkEct1Yg
     0di6sBafkMDOdVyuhF7DcDLii1fYpAdg45MrUlJpD6/ggs+k4j0fQMKNvLoxJIXNcm
     X8WynhKvMzQSrKSVnbLikcyHRUtuv9Ufd7s9IaYUv+cd68q953GEeKFZIMHKXHjMve
     WyNk4BFUU5PCtL+z9wmuThheTMIoEeCbEHab+IlSQVoeRnYENPaQEJ1O6gww7uygB5
     xp86feiqaaIz8camaN3g1uWLDrB4bITtZk/m+mzIjs6VZJkM7cJLvUSRsXx3zWTwCi
     vJwYR5YfdtSug==
Received: from 127.0.0.1 (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by systemalerts9.mailchimp.com (Mailchimp) with ESMTP id 4DhR1j3NWdzJKFDPJ
    for <yapirar954@mayhco.com>; Thu, 18 Feb 2021 20:21:29 +0000 (GMT)
From: =?utf-8?Q?Mailchimp=20Client=20Services?= <clientservices@mailchimp.com>
Reply-To: =?utf-8?Q?Mailchimp=20Client=20Services?= <clientservices@mailchimp.com>
To:  <yapirar954@mayhco.com>
Date: Thu, 18 Feb 2021 20:21:29 +0000
Message-ID: <05e7397e7ab.20210218202129@systemalerts9.mailchimp.com>
X-Mailer: MailChimp Mailer - **CID0f941039475e7397e7ab**
X-Campaign: mailchimp0.0f94103947
X-campaignid: mailchimp0.0f94103947
X-Report-Abuse: Please report abuse for this campaign here: https://mailchimp.com/contact/abuse/?u=0&id=0f94103947&e=5e7397e7ab
X-MC-User: 0
X-Feedback-ID: 0:0.0f94103947:usx:mc
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: OOF, AutoReply
Subject: Activate your Mailchimp account
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_----------=_MCPart_1894767556"


--_----------=_MCPart_1894767556
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"

We're glad you're here dadafafdadaazdzad.


-------------------
Activate Your Account: https://us1.admin.mailchimp.com/signup/confirm?id=fde8758bfee8a9b1d56fb6a17&eid=170503bbeb8abcdac24c&kme=Clicked%20Activate%20Account%20Email&kmi=dadafafdadaazdzad&referral=
-------------------
(Just confirming you're you)


-----------------------------------------------
https://www.mailchimp.com
675 Ponce De Leon Ave NE Suite 5000 Atlanta, GA 30308 USA

--_----------=_MCPart_1894767556
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"; format="fixed"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!doctype html>=0A<html>=0A    <head>=0A        <!-- trx_0075 -->=0A   =
     <meta charset=3D"UTF-8">=0A        <meta name=3D"viewport" content=
=3D"width=3Ddevice-width=2C initial-scale=3D1"/>=0A        <meta http-eq=
uiv=3D"X-UA-Compatible" content=3D"IE=3Dedge">=0A        <title>Activate=
 your Mailchimp account</title>=0A=0A        <style type=3D"text/css">=
=0A            /*////// RESET STYLES //////*/=0A            p{margin:10p=
x 0; padding:0;}=0A            table{border-collapse:collapse;}=0A     =
       h1=2C h2=2C h3=2C h4=2C h5=2C h6{display:block; margin:0; padding=
:0;}=0A            img=2C a img{border:0; height:auto; outline:none; tex=
t-decoration:none;}=0A            body=2C #bodyTable=2C #bodyCell{height=
:100%; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%;}=0A=0A            /*////// CLIEN=
T-SPECIFIC STYLES //////*/=0A            #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force=
 Outlook 2007 and up to provide a "view in browser" message. */=0A     =
       @-ms-viewport{width:device-width;} /* Force IE "snap mode" to ren=
der widths normally. */=0A            img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic=
;} /* Force IE to smoothly render resized images. */=0A            table=
{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} /* Remove spacing between=
 tables in Outlook Desktop. */=0A            .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .=
ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Outlook.com to display emails at ful=
l width. */=0A            p=2C a=2C li=2C td=2C blockquote{mso-line-heig=
ht-rule:exactly;} /* Force Outlook Desktop to render line heights as the=
y're originally set. */=0A            a[href^=3D"tel"]=2C a[href^=3D"sms=
"]{color:inherit; cursor:default; text-decoration:none;} /* Force mobile=
 devices to inherit declared link styles. */=0A            p=2C a=2C li=
=2C td=2C body=2C table=2C blockquote{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; -webkit=
-text-size-adjust:100%;} /* Prevent Windows- and Webkit-based platforms=
 from changing declared text sizes. */=0A            .ExternalClass=2C .=
ExternalClass p=2C .ExternalClass td=2C .ExternalClass div=2C .ExternalC=
lass span=2C .ExternalClass font{line-height:100%;} /* Force Outlook.com=
 to display line heights normally. */=0A            a[x-apple-data-detec=
tors]{color:inherit !important; text-decoration:none !important; font-si=
ze:inherit !important; font-family:inherit !important; font-weight:inher=
it !important; line-height:inherit !important;} /* Force iOS devices to=
 heed link styles set in CSS. */=0A=0A            /*////// EMAIL STYLES=
 //////*/=0A            #footerContent a{color:#007C89 !important;}=0A =
           #button a{text-decoration:none;} /* Necessary for Outlook on=
 Windows Phone */=0A=0A            /*////// MOBILE STYLES //////*/=0A  =
          @media only screen and (max-width:480px){=0A                bo=
dy{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;}=0A               =
 h1{font-size:24px !important;}=0A                .footerContent{padding=
-bottom:0 !important;}=0A                .footerContent p{border-bottom:=
1px solid #EFEEEA; font-size:13px !important; padding-bottom:40px !impor=
tant;}=0A                .utilityLink{border-bottom:1px solid #EFEEEA; d=
isplay:block; font-size:13px !important; padding-top:15px; padding-botto=
m:15px;}=0A                .mobileHide{display:none; visibility:hidden;}=
=0A            }=0A        </style>=0A    </head>=0A    <body bgcolor=3D=
"#EFEEEA">=0A        <center>=0A            <table align=3D"center" bgco=
lor=3D"#EFEEEA" border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" height=
=3D"100%" width=3D"100%" id=3D"bodyTable">=0A                <tr>=0A   =
                 <td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top" id=3D"bodyCell" sty=
le=3D"padding-bottom:60px;">=0A                        <span style=3D"co=
lor:#FFE01B; display:none; font-size:0px; height:0px; visibility:hidden;=
 width:0px;">You're almost ready to get started!</span>=0A             =
           <table align=3D"center" border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellsp=
acing=3D"0" width=3D"100%">=0A                            <!-- BEGIN HEA=
DER // -->=0A                            <tr>=0A                       =
         <td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top" bgcolor=3D"#FFE01B" valign=
=3D"top" style=3D"background-color:#FFE01B;">=0A                       =
             <!--[if gte mso 9]>=0A                                    <=
table align=3D"center" border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0"=
 width=3D"640">=0A                                    <tr>=0A          =
                          <td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top" width=3D"6=
40">=0A                                    <![endif]-->=0A             =
                       <table align=3D"center" border=3D"0" cellpadding=
=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" style=3D"max-width:640px;" width=3D"100%" class=
=3D"emailContainer">=0A                                        <tr>=0A =
                                           <td align=3D"center" valign=
=3D"top" style=3D"padding:40px;">=0A                                   =
             <a href=3D"https://www.mailchimp.com/" target=3D"_blank" st=
yle=3D"text-decoration:none;"><img alt=3D"Mailchimp" src=3D"https://cdn-=
images.mailchimp.com/template_images/cxp_2018/mc-freddie-dark@2x.png" wi=
dth=3D"60" style=3D"border:0; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:'Helvetica Neue=
'=2C Helvetica=2C Arial=2C Verdana=2C sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-w=
eight:400; height:auto; letter-spacing:-1px; padding:0; margin:0; outlin=
e:none; text-align:center; text-decoration:none;" /></a>=0A            =
                                </td>=0A                               =
         </tr>=0A                                        <tr>=0A       =
                                     <td style=3D"background-color:#FFFF=
FF; padding-top:40px;">&nbsp;</td>=0A                                  =
      </tr>=0A                                    </table>=0A          =
                          <!--[if gte mso 9]>=0A                       =
             </td>=0A                                    </tr>=0A      =
                              </table>=0A                              =
      <![endif]-->=0A                                </td>=0A          =
                  </tr>=0A                            <!-- // END HEADER=
 -->=0A                            <!-- BEGIN BODY AND FOOTER // -->=0A=
                            <tr>=0A                                <td a=
lign=3D"center" valign=3D"top" valign=3D"top">=0A                      =
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>=0A                                   =
 <table align=3D"center" border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0=
" width=3D"640">=0A                                    <tr>=0A         =
                           <td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top" width=3D"=
640">=0A                                    <![endif]-->=0A            =
                        <table align=3D"center" bgcolor=3D"#FFFFFF" bord=
er=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" style=3D"background-color:#=
FFFFFF; max-width:640px;" width=3D"100%" class=3D"emailContainer">=0A  =
                                      <tr>=0A                          =
                  <td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top" bgcolor=3D"#FFFFFF=
" valign=3D"top" style=3D"padding-right:40px; padding-bottom:40px; paddi=
ng-left:40px; ">=0A                                                <h1 s=
tyle=3D"color:#241C15; font-family:Georgia=2C Times=2C 'Times New Roman'=
=2C serif; font-size:30px; font-style:normal; font-weight:400; line-heig=
ht:42px; letter-spacing:normal; margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center;"=
>We're glad you're here=2C<br />dadafafdadaazdzad.</h1>=0A             =
                               </td>=0A                                =
        </tr>=0A                                        <tr>=0A        =
                                    <td align=3D"center" valign=3D"middl=
e" style=3D"padding-right:40px; padding-bottom:60px; padding-left:40px;"=
>=0A                                                <table border=3D"0"=
 cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0">=0A                               =
                     <tr>=0A                                           =
             <td align=3D"center" bgcolor=3D"#007C89" id=3D"button"><a h=
ref=3D"https://us1.admin.mailchimp.com/signup/confirm?id=3Dfde8758bfee8a=
9b1d56fb6a17&eid=3D170503bbeb8abcdac24c&kme=3DClicked%20Activate%20Accou=
nt%20Email&kmi=3Ddadafafdadaazdzad&referral=3D" target=3D"_blank" style=
=3D"border-radius:0; border:1px solid #007C89; color:#FFFFFF; display:in=
line-block; font-size:16px; font-family:'Helvetica Neue'=2C Helvetica=2C=
 Arial=2C Verdana=2C sans-serif; font-weight:400; letter-spacing:.3px; p=
adding:20px; text-decoration:none;">Activate Account</a>=0A            =
                                            </td>=0A                   =
                                 </tr>=0A                              =
                  </table>=0A                                          =
  </td>=0A                                        </tr>=0A             =
                           <tr>=0A                                     =
       <td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top" style=3D"padding-right:40px;=
 padding-bottom:40px; padding-left:40px; ">=0A                         =
                       <p style=3D"color:#6A655F; font-family:'Helvetica=
 Neue'=2C Helvetica=2C Arial=2C Verdana=2C sans-serif; font-size:16px; f=
ont-style:normal; font-weight:400; line-height:42px; letter-spacing:norm=
al; margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center;">(Just confirming you're you=
.)</p>=0A                                            </td>=0A          =
                              </tr>=0A                                 =
       <tr>=0A                                            <td align=3D"c=
enter" valign=3D"top" class=3D"footerContent" style=3D"border-top:2px so=
lid #EFEEEA; color:#6A655F; font-family:'Helvetica Neue'=2C Helvetica=2C=
 Arial=2C Verdana=2C sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:400; line-h=
eight:24px; padding-top:40px; padding-bottom:40px; text-align:center;">=
=0A                                                <p style=3D"color:#6A=
655F; font-family:'Helvetica Neue'=2C Helvetica=2C Arial=2C Verdana=2C s=
ans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:400; line-height:24px; padding:0=
 20px; margin:0; text-align:center;">=C2=A9 2001-2021 Mailchimp<sup>=C2=
=AE</sup>=2C All Rights Reserved.<br /><a style=3D"color:#6A655F; text-d=
ecoration:none;">675 Ponce De Leon Ave NE =E2=80=A2 Suite 5000 =E2=80=A2=
 Atlanta=2C GA 30308 USA</a></p>=0A                                    =
            <a href=3D"https://www.mailchimp.com/contact/" target=3D"_bl=
ank" style=3D"color:#007C89; font-weight:500; text-decoration:none;" cla=
ss=3D"utilityLink">Contact Us</a><span class=3D"mobileHide"> &nbsp; =E2=
=80=A2 &nbsp; </span><a href=3D"https://mailchimp.com/legal/terms/" targ=
et=3D"_blank" style=3D"color:#007C89; font-weight:500; text-decoration:n=
one;" class=3D"utilityLink">Terms of Use</a><span class=3D"mobileHide">=
 &nbsp; =E2=80=A2 &nbsp; </span><a href=3D"https://mailchimp.com/legal/p=
rivacy/" target=3D"_blank" style=3D"color:#007C89; font-weight:500; text=
-decoration:none;" class=3D"utilityLink">Privacy Policy</a>=0A         =
                                   </td>=0A                            =
            </tr>=0A                                    </table>=0A    =
                                <!--[if gte mso 9]>=0A                 =
                   </td>=0A                                    </tr>=0A=
                                    </table>=0A                        =
            <![endif]-->=0A                                </td>=0A    =
                        </tr>=0A                            <!-- // END=
 BODY AND FOOTER -->=0A                        </table>=0A             =
       </td>=0A                </tr>=0A            </table>=0A        </=
center>=0A    </body>=0A</html>=0A
--_----------=_MCPart_1894767556--
```

I'm writing a video tutorial that aim to demistify raw email message. I do it while learning the thing and I found a lot of information but some stuffs are more hard to understand. I understand that this Internet Message is formatted by the RFC5322, but don't get how to distinguish the header from the body.

I see there is a lot of  `--_----------=_MCPart_XXXXXXXXX--`. I Think that MC stands for Mail Chimp because that mail come from them but what is `--_----------` ? is it Standard ? Also there is two field "Received:" why ?

Comment: I don't see an information __security__ question here, i.e. off-topic here. It is about understanding how a mail is structured, without any relation to security.

Answer (score 1):

Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME), defined by [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) makes different blocks of content. These are separated by *boundaries*.

The boundary is set in the `Content-Type:` header.

Your mail contains the header

> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_----------=_MCPart_1894767556"

This means that the following content is presented in several alternative ways (all of them have the same content, albeit in different formats, the client should pick the last one it can handle, see [section 5.1.4 of rfc2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.4)), and it uses a boundary of «_----------=_MCPart_1894767556»

The parts will then start with two dashes and the boundary that was defined, up to finally finish with two dashes, the boundary and two dashes.

The boundary itself is a random string. It only needs not to appear inside any of the content. It is possible to have several multipart pieces one inside another, and so it is important that an outer boundary isn't also used inside, as well as the boundary string itself not appearing in the text.

You will find different ways in which those boundaries are generated. Apparently MaiChip code uses "_----------=*MCPart*" followed by a number.

As for the other questions:

> don't get how to distinguish the header from the body.

The headers and the body are separated by an empty line. The body starts after the first empty line.

Also note, each MIME part has a header section by itself. I would recommend starting with a mail sent just in plaintext, before diving into multipart ones.

> Also there is two field "Received:" why ?

It passed through two servers (and I guess you removed some more Received lines, since it would have needed to reach your mail server, as well).

Answer (score 0):

> I don't get how to distinguish the header from the body.

The first empty line in the message separates the message header from the message body.

> I see there is a lot of --_----------=_MCPart_XXXXXXXXX--

In the last line of the message header, you'll notice:

boundary="_----------=_MCPart_1894767556"

This defines the MIME boundary.  The MIME boundary is used to separate each MIME part of the message - e.g. the plaintext part of the message, the richtext (or HTML) part of the message, each attachment, etc.  It can be any string, but it's common for it to contain '-' characters, and mail clients typically put their own 'fingerprints' on this (as you noticed with mail chimp using MC).  Boundaries denoting the beginning of a mime part have '--' prepended.  Boundaries marking the end of a mime part have '--' prepended and '--' appended.

> Also there is two field "Received:" why ?

It's not unusual for a message to be routed through several mail servers between the sender and the recipient.  Read the headers from the bottom to the top to see how the message was routed through different mail servers as it made its way from the sender to the recipient.  Each mail server that the message is routed through prepends a `Received:` line to the message header, showing its own hostname, the hostname of the server it received the message from, and a time stamp.